# Override scrollTo jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, scrollto, mousewheel

I'm currently using Ariel Flesler's "scrollTo" plugin for jQuery:
http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Example of it in use here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aU7J6/9/

While it's scrolling down, you'll notice that you can't override it with the mouse wheel or scroll bar. Is there any way to do this? (particularly the mouse wheel)

**Update:**
I've tried to `stop()` the window on a `scroll` event, but it isn't working (fiddle updated with this). The scroll event is triggered when the animation starts. Replacing `scroll` with `mousewheel` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You could `stop()` the animation on `scroll` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specifically tell the scrollable instance to stop, you can access it by using `._scrollable()` method of the plugin, I've updated your fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/aU7J6/35/

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', function() {

    console.log('scrolling!');
    $(this)._scrollable().stop();

})
```

Documented at http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks! You'll get the +50 when I'm permitted to send it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/dQeZd/1/

Changed to using body as the selector, which will stop the animation.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', function() {
    console.log('scrolling');
    $('html, body').stop();
});
```

This actually is going to help me with one of my projects too - great question.